# Parsing "Collection of Images" with json to cpp doesn't work

Tags: c++, json, sfml, tiled

so I have a Tiled map, I have a "based on a tileset image" tileset, and a "Collection of Images" tileset with a few images of different sizes inside.

Everything works fine, but not for the "Collection of Images" tileset and parsing this with json to our game.

Here is the layer loader from json to cpp. It loads the layer and it works fine, if I add something to the map from "Collection of Images" tileset, it is ignored. I can still collide with it, but it isn't shown.

```
void MapMaker::loadLayer(Json::Value &layer, std::list<Object *> &objects, TileSize tileSize) {

MapLayer *tmp = new MapLayer(tileSize);

tmp->width = layer["width"].asInt();
tmp->height = layer["height"].asInt();

memset(tmp->tileMap, 0, sizeof(tmp->tileMap));

for(size_t i = 0; i < layer["data"].size(); ++i)
    tmp->tileMap[i] = layer["data"][(int)i].asInt();

tmp->isCollisionLayer = layer["properties"]["Collision"].asBool();

objects.push_back(tmp);

}
```

The crates in the images are from the "Collection of Images" tileset
[image: image with crates]

but in-game these are gone, but the player can still collide with them...
[image: image without crates]

I bet there is some code missing. if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

[I have here the json map file if needed](https://pastebin.com/rEvRDnHK).

Comment: This looks more related to your rendering code. What are you using to render the map?

Answer (score 1):

Your "crates" tileset layer in your JSON is empty...

Hence no crates are drawn. The collision detection is (assumingly?) computed from invisible objects in your layer named "collision", thus you can collide - but you don't see crates.

Comment: BTW: you can see this if you open your JSON in Tiled, and then switch off visibility for all but the crates layer ;)